# Average calculation through time scale (SQL Server) - preparation for charting

Tags: sql-server, charts

I have the following table in SQL Server Express edition:

```
Time Device Value
0:00 1      2
0:01 2      3
0:03 3      5
0:03 1      3
0:13 2      5
0:22 1      7
0:34 3      5
0:35 2      6
0:37 1      5
```

The table is used to log the events of different devices which are reporting their latest values. What I'd like to do is to prepare the data in a way that I'd present the average data through time scale and eventually create a chart using this data. I've manipulated this example data in Excel in the following way:

```
Time Average value
0:03 3,666666667
0:13 4,333333333
0:22 5,666666667
0:34 5,666666667
0:35 6
0:37 5,333333333
```

So, at time 0:03 I need to take latest data I have in the table and calculate the average. In this case it's (3+3+5)/3=3,67. At time 0:13 the steps would be repeated, and again at 0:22,...

As I'd like to leave the everything within the SQL table (I wouldn't like to create any service with C# or similar which would grab the data and store it into some other table)

I'd like to know the following:

1. is this the right approach or should I use some other concept of calculating the average for charting data preparation?
2. if yes, what's the best approach to implement it? Table view, function within the database, stored procedure (which would be called from the charting API)?
3. any suggestions on how to implement this?

Thank you in advance.
Mark

### Update 1

In the mean time I got one idea how to approach to this problem. I'd kindly ask you for your comments on it and I'd still need some help in getting the problem resolved.
So, the idea is to crosstab the table like this:

```
Time    Device1Value    Device2Value    Device3Value
0:00    2           NULL            NULL
0:01    NULL            3           NULL
0:03    3           NULL            5
0:13    NULL            5           NULL
0:22    7           NULL            NULL
0:34    NULL            NULL            5
0:35    NULL            6           NULL
0:37    5           NULL            NULL
```

The query for this to happen would be:

```
SELECT Time,
(SELECT Stock FROM dbo.Event WHERE Time = S.Time AND Device = 1) AS Device1Value,
(SELECT Stock FROM dbo.Event WHERE Time = S.Time AND Device = 2) AS Device2Value,
(SELECT Stock FROM dbo.Event WHERE Time = S.Time AND Device = 3) AS Device3Value
FROM dbo.Event S GROUP BY Time
```

What I'd still need to do is to write a user defined function and call it within this query which would write last available value in case of NULL and if the last available value doesn't exist it would leave NULL value. With this function I'd get the following results:

```
Time    Device1Value    Device2Value    Device3Value
0:00    2           NULL            NULL
0:01    2           3           NULL
0:03    3           3           5
0:13    3           5           5
0:22    7           5           5
0:34    7           5           5
0:35    7           6           5
0:37    5           6           5
```

And by having this results I'd be able to calculate the average for each time by only SUMing up the 3 relevant columns and dividing it by count (in this case 3). For NULL I'd use 0 value.

Can anybody suggest how to create a user defined function for replacing NULL values with latest value?

### Update 2

Thanks Martin.
This query worked but it took almost 21 minutes to go through the 13.576 lines which is far too much.

The final query I used was:

```
SELECT Time,
(SELECT TOP 1 Stock FROM dbo.Event e WHERE e.Time <= S.Time AND Device = 1 ORDER BY e.Time DESC) AS Device1Value,
(SELECT TOP 1 Stock FROM dbo.Event e WHERE e.Time <= S.Time AND Device = 2 ORDER BY e.Time DESC) AS Device2Value,
(SELECT TOP 1 Stock FROM dbo.Event e WHERE e.Time <= S.Time AND Device = 3 ORDER BY e.Time DESC) AS Device3Value
FROM dbo.Event S GROUP BY Time
```

but I've extended it to 10 devices.

I agree that this is not the best way to do it. Is there any other way to prepare the data for the average calculation because this takes just too much of the processing.

Comment: How do you get (3+3+5)/3=3.67 at time 0.03? And the other values? The only one that makes sense is 0:35 = 6

Comment: @gbn: 0:03 (device 1)=3, 0:03 (device 3)=5, 0:01 (device 2)=3. So, 3+5+3=11, and average of 11 for 3 devices is 3,67.

Comment: I downvoted your two answers as additional info should get edited into the question not posted as an answer. I upvoted your question though so the overall effect on your reputation is more or less neutral!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. It uses the "Quirky Update" approach to filling in the gaps. This relies on an undocumented behaviour so you may prefer to use a cursor for this.

```
DECLARE @SourceData TABLE([Time] TIME, Device INT, value FLOAT) 

INSERT INTO @SourceData
SELECT '0:00',1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:01',2,3 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:03',3,5 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:03',1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:13',2,5 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:22',1,7 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:34',3,5 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:35',2,6 UNION ALL
SELECT '0:37',1,5 

CREATE TABLE #tmpResults
(
[Time] Time primary key,
[1] FLOAT,
[2] FLOAT,
[3] FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpResults
SELECT [Time],[1],[2],[3]
FROM @SourceData 
PIVOT ( MAX(value) FOR Device IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS pvt
ORDER BY [Time];

DECLARE @1 FLOAT, @2 FLOAT, @3 FLOAT

UPDATE #tmpResults
SET @1 = [1] = ISNULL([1],@1),
    @2 = [2] = ISNULL([2],@2),
    @3 = [3] = ISNULL([3],@3)


SELECT [Time],
       (SELECT AVG(device)
        FROM   (SELECT [1] AS device
                UNION ALL
                SELECT [2]
                UNION ALL
                SELECT [3]) t) AS [Average value]
FROM   #tmpResults  

DROP TABLE #tmpResults
```

Comment: I'll test this one. In the mean time I've found another way to get the results which I'll post as an answer. It's using the CASE function.

Comment: Hi Martin, your example works As-Is (with temp tables), but in practice I have an issue with time column as it's set as primary key and I can't use it as primary key (the time can repeat). Therefore I've created another column as sequence which is set as auto increment identity, but in this case I then have a problem that when using a pivot function I get the same time in two separate rows (e.g. in case of 00:03). Do you have any idea how to overcome that obstacle?

Comment: What do you mean the time can repeat? The same device can have 2 different values simultaneously? BTW Stack Overflow is a Q & A site not a forum. Answers should **only** be used for things that answer the question not random bits of additional information.

Comment: Martin, tahnks for the reminder. I'm new to this site and don't yet fully know how to use it. Your solution was working but I had to make some modifications as it can happen that within the same time two messages arrive and therefore time cannot be used as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the possible solutions which I found is far more efficient (less than a second for 14.574 lines). I haven't yet had time to review the results in details but on the first hand it looks promising. This is the code for the 3 device example:
SELECT      Time,
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '1' THEN Stock ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '2' THEN Stock ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '3' THEN Stock ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
FROM        dbo.Event 
GROUP BY    Time 
ORDER BY    Time

In any case I'll test the code provided by Martin to see if it makes any difference to the results.

Comment: That just does the cross tab. It doesn't do anything about filling in NULLS with the previous value.

Comment: That's not the case. The code does exactly what's expected from it. The problem I have now is with the real data where I'm having a scenario where I have at the same time (e.g. at 00:03) two different entries for the same device. Now I need to figure out how to filter out the latest one (I have a sequence which is telling me which is the latest message of specific device within the table).

Comment: The issue with two different data on the same time is now resolved. I've used a subquery where I've first selected the MAX sequence out of all data and group it by Device and Time and then added the event column to this table through inner join where I used device and sequence as a key for joining the tables together. The final code is:

Comment: SELECT      x.Time,  
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '1' THEN Event ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '2' THEN Event ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
SUM(CASE MAC WHEN '3' THEN Event ELSE 0 END) Device1Value, 
FROM       (SELECT     MAX(sequence) AS seq, Device AS d, time as Time
                       FROM          dbo.Event
                       GROUP BY Device, time) AS x INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Event AS s ON s.Device = x.d AND s.sequence = x.seq 
GROUP BY    x.Time 
ORDER BY    x.Time